# WCF Service - no global.asax

Tags: wcf

Is there supposed to be a global.asax.cs file created as part of creating a new WCF service project?  I don't see one.  Do I have to manually add this?

Comment: What do you want to do with global.asax. I'm not sure all of the events will fire in the case of WCF, if _any_ of them will.

Comment: I'm trying to do a RESTful WCF :).  Service routes I think I may need?

Comment: for example I thinlk I'll need to add routes such as :             RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("FoodService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(FoodService)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create a WCF Service Application in Visual Studio 2012, I don't get a global.asax, so I guess you'll have to create one.